# Evolving thought process and design thinking

Tags: c#, design, architecture, self-improvement, training

I'm working as a software developer for around 8 years now and have worked with mostly companies offering outsourcing services.The challenge so far was mostly - learn the new tech, showcase through a prototype/POC and implement it in the assigned project. Over the years, technologies changed, but nature of work remained the same - javascript, jquery, webforms, silverlight, MVC, etc. But now, am trying to transition to a software consultant role and one of the feedbacks that I recieved was - "*Try to think in depth, as to not just use a feature but to relate it to the most basic concept that you know*." e.g. as a best practice for string concatenation in C#, we know that we should be using stringbuillder and also know why we should be using it (string immutability), but the question was - *How would you implement a StringBuilder class from scratch?*

I'm not sure how to train myself for becoming ready for design thinking and making myself ready for in-depth thinking and analysis (since most of day to day tasks never require such rigorous drill-down).

PS: Sorry for long question and also even though the question is not suitable for platform, I would still be happy if anybody could point to a correct forum/community where i can reach out for guidance.

Comment: that's a weird question to ask. Are they testing your low level.net knowledge or is it a meta question? ie "copy the existing string builder", "implement memory space tests"

Comment: Actually, they were looking for people in senior roles to build reliable and scalable solutions. They wanted to check if I can only leverage existing solutions to a problem or build custom solutions too.

Comment: not sure i would call "using stringbuilder" "leveraging an existing system"

Comment: if its just an interview question then I guess its off topic and general advice applies. "Of course normally you can just use an existing component, but here is an example of where I had to do a deep dive and implement a custom solution..."

Comment: @Ewan education advice is what is off topic. An on topic question asked in an interview isn't off topic unless the only goal is for us to magically know what the interviewer was thinking.

Comment: @candied_orange although I agree with you in principle, this is quite a slippery matter, see [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)

Comment: *How would you implement a StringBuilder class from scratch?* -  Writing one's own version of existing language features, libraries, framework is very poor judgement. I have seen very smart people do this and totally hose a project. However, *extending* (inheriting) a framework class is generally a good thing.

Comment: @gnat here’s the problem. While we certainly have a bad history with interview questions there is a valuable issue here that is being wasted simply because we can’t see how to edit the question into something that can be reopened.

Comment: *how to ...* - Use every "day to day" assignment to research/review/study  the language's documentation of the classes, methods, etc. used. That existing code is good practical context for considering all those technical implementation issues.

Comment: I am thankful to the community for paying heed to a closed question. If it helps, my intent was to reform my thought process to start looking at things differently, to see what is happening "behind the scenes". I wasn't just looking for answers to the questions posed, but to reform the way I should be thinking and working to grow my grasp over subject. Just for benefit of discussion, another uncommon question I faced was - What happens when we use the ".ToList()" function? I've gone through the Microsoft source code which is openly available now, but that wasn't a habit with me earlier. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you implement a StringBuilder class from scratch?

By thinking very seriously about why I have to implement `StringBuilder` from scratch.

The proper reaction to that question is to ask "why?". Without a good reason *why* all you're doing is showing off that you know how to implement your own `StringBuilder` if stranded on a desert island. Not typically useful.

Now if the current `StringBuilder` has a bug that's causing you trouble or is missing a feature that would be useful then being able to reimplement it would be handy. Being able to extend it would be convenient.

> "Try to think in depth, as to not just use a feature but to relate it to the most basic concept that you know." e.g. as a best practice for string concatenation in C#, we know that we should be using `StringBuilder` and also know why we should be using it (string immutability) -

String immutability isn't why. A single concatenation of immutable strings works just fine without `StringBuilder`. The problem is multiple concatenations can't be optimized if you don't consider all the strings first. Doing that lets you allocate enough memory for all of them at the start without allocating O(n<sup>2</sup>) more memory.  Big O optimization isn't just about CPU cycles. Memory use is important as well. Simply making strings mutable doesn't make this problem go away. This is about when you figure out how much memory you need, before or after you've used a bunch of memory you really don't.

Understand that and you might be able to reimplement `StringBuilder` without embarrassing yourself. Also might help you realize when fanatically insisting on using `StringBuilder` every time isn't warranted.  If you've never heard the [Shlemiel The Painter](https://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter) story I suggest you give it a read.

> Try to think in depth

I read this as: show me you can do more than regurgitate rules to follow by rote. Show me you've thought about why. Software development is chuck full of people following rules they don't really understand. Are you just another one of them?

> I'm not sure how to train myself for becoming ready for design thinking and making myself ready for in-depth thinking and analysis (since most of day to day tasks never require such rigorous drill-down).

Keep asking why. Keep trying to explain why. You haven't mastered a topic until you can explain it to someone who keeps asking why.

Comment: thanks a lot, this helps. I'll start paying more attention to why best practices are indeed best and look time-space complexity more closely.

Comment: @VaibhavSingla keep in mind, if you know n will be small, no ones going to care.